# Android change button background

Tags: android, button, background, selection, selectionchanged

I want to reverse the colors (text & background) of my button when it is clicked.

I have the following XML files. When I test it, I can see the text color changes but the background color remains the same. I could not see what I'm missing.

`layout.xml`

```
...
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_btn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:text="start"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
    android:fontFamily="@string/font_family"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
...
```

`button_text_color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/miops_dark_red" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

`button_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/miops_dark_red" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/miops_dark_red" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="1dp"
                android:left="1dp"
                android:right="1dp"
                android:top="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I managed to solve the problem;
I have modified `background.xml` as followed;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed"
        android:state_focused="true"
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_background_released"
        />
</selector>
```

and added folowing two;

`button_background_pressed.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/miops_dark_red" />
<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />
</shape>
```

`button_background_released.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/miops_dark_red" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mLogin.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
mLogin.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(AESConstants.RED_DOWN,AESConstants.GREEN_DOWN,AESConstants.BLUE_DOWN));
}
else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
mLogin.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(AESConstants.RED_UP,AESConstants.GREEN_UP,AESConstants.BLUE_UP));
}
return false;
}
});
```

This is one approach You can do something like this from code itself instead from the layout files

Answer (score 0):

change your btn_bak.xml for the code below (or just add the gradient, which i think is the problem), you use only border (stroke). The below i use in my app, and if i understood your question correct you can easily modify it to your needs. 
If gives the button a yellow background when pressed, and the black is just a frame around the button and if nothing, than white background.
Tell me if it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/yellow1"
            android:endColor="@color/yellow"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/black" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:top="20dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/white"
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:angle="270" />
        <padding
            android:top="20dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    private void setBackgroundColor(String color,Button btn) {

```
    GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)btn.getBackground();
    drawable.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    drawable.setStroke(4,Color.parseColor(color));
    btn.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
}
```